# How to shutdown a servlet container from within a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, containers

Is there a *portable* way to request a Servlet container to shutdown **gracefully**, from within a servlet?

By portable I mean a technique that will work on all standard compliant containers (Tomcat, Jetty, Winstone, etc).

Note that this is the opposite of the Servlet.destroy() method, which gets called when the container is taking the servlet down.

Comment: There is no portable way, because it's a bad idea.

Comment: Hmm.. So how can I gracefully bring down the container (for upgrades, maintenance) in a portable way?

Comment: @HRJ: To put it nicely, you don't.  You use the container's specific shutdown sequence.

Comment: Whoops, I never said why: You don't because your application can't tell whether other applications are running in the servlet container.

Comment: @Bemrose I understand your view. But, I am interested in the "mechanisms" not the "policies".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.exit();

If you are running with no SecurityManager.

EDIT: Is this graceful? This depends on containers.

On Tomcat, if you call it with 0

```
  System.exit(0);
```

It's as graceful as shutdown.sh or Catalina.stop() because the shutdown hook simply calls stop().

Comment: On further thought, and in the absence of other solutions, this does seem like a good way. The container could register shutdown hooks with the VM to ensure gracefulness.

Comment: There are no guarantees the server has registered any shutdown hooks, though. That depends on how the server is implemented. It also has concurrency problems, as requests made simultaneously with the shutdown request can be killed when in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Bad, bad idea. Especially in a cloud. But I don't blame ZZ Coder for this answer. The of course, the SecurityManager was mentioned; I just hope anyone taking this advice as a true answer knows what they are doing.

Comment: What would you do if you run out of memory? This is the easiest way to get out of it without complicated monitoring software. We have a daemon will start it right back up.

Comment: You didn't mention the daemon and I don't think you are running your application in a shared environment.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way defined in the [Java EE Servlet Spec](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/reference/api/index.html) that I know of, which there would need to be for it to be portable.

The link it to the servlet API specs, so if there's such a way, it'll be documented there somewhere.

I also agree that it'd be a really bad idea for one servlet to be able to shut down the container!